# flask-tornado CTRL+C termination in windows

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, flask, tornado

Below code:

```
from tornado.wsgi import WSGIContainer
from tornado.httpserver import HTTPServer
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop  


def start(app, port=8080):  
      http_server = HTTPServer(WSGIContainer(app))
      http_server.listen(port)
      try:
          IOLoop.instance().start()
      except KeyboardInterrupt:
          print "stop"
          IOLoop.instance().stop()
```

I want to stop tornado server using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>PauseBreak</kbd> in Windows, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> does not stop it in CMD.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PauseBreak</kbd> does stop CMD and terminate python.exe, but does not show "stop".

How to enter KeyboardInterrupt in windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows, the `select()` function (which IOLoop uses internally) is not interruptible (http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t722370-windows-select-select-timeout-and-keyboardinterrupt.html).  The easiest workaround is to start a `PeriodicCallback` (it doesn't have to do anything; just an empty function); when the callback is triggered the IOLoop will wake up and the KeyboardInterrupt exception will be raised.